# Solving $3^x = 2^y + 1$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{N}^2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I consider the following equation

$$ 3^x = 1 + 2^y \tag{$\star$} $$

with $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ and $y \geq 3$.

I would like to show that :

> $$ 3^x \equiv 1 \; [2^y] \; \Leftrightarrow \; 2^{y-2} \mid x. $$

I assume that $3^x \equiv 1 \; [2^y]$. Writing

$$ 3^x = \sum_{k=0}^{x} C_{x}^{k} 2^k = 2^x + x 2^{x-1} + \ldots + 2x + 1 $$

I have that $3^x \equiv 1 \; [2^y]$ is equivalent to :

$$ 2^x + x 2^{x-1} + \ldots + 2x \equiv 0 \; [2^y]. $$

This is also equivalent to :

$$ 2^{x-1} + x 2^{x-2} + \ldots + x \equiv 0 \; [2^{y-1}]. $$

Then, I am unsure about how to proceed. I would like to assume that $x > y$ and then, it would follow that $2^{x-1} \equiv 0 \; [2^{y-1}]$. Therefore, I would end up with :

$$ x \big( 2^{x-2} + \ldots + 1 ) \equiv 0 \; [2^{y-1}]. $$

Since $\operatorname{gcd}\big( 2^{y-1}, 2^{x-2} + \ldots + 1 \big) = 1$, it follows that $2^{y-1} \mid x$. But this is not the expected result. Where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: When you write $x2^{x-2}+\cdots+x=x(2^{x-2}+\cdots+1)$, you are tacitly assuming that $x$ divides *all* the binomial coefficients $C_x^k$ for $1\le k\le x-1$.  That's only true when $x$ is a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $x$ can't bigger than $y$, as then obviously $3^x > 1 + 2^y$.

Another way to solve the question is to note that if $y \ge 2$ then $x$ is even, because $4 \mid 2^y = 3^x - 1$. Therefeore if $x=2k$ we have:

$$2^y = 3^{2k} - 1 = (3^k - 1)(3^k + 1)$$

But now $\gcd(3^k - 1, 3^k + 1) = 2$ and from the above equation we must have $3^k - 1 = 2$ and $3^k + 1 = 2^{y-1}$. From the first equation we can conclude $k=1$ and so $x=2$ and plugging in the second one we get $y=3$. These are the only possibilities for $y \ge 2$

Now look at the case $y=1$ separately and you will obtain another solution, namely $x=1; y=1$

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to show that :
>
> $$ 3^x \equiv 1 \; [2^y] \; \Leftrightarrow \; 2^{y-2} \mid x. $$

To show this, I would use that, for every pair of positive integers $(a,s)$ where $s$ is odd, there exists an odd integer $t$ such that

$$3^{2^as}-1=2^{a+2}t\tag1$$

(the proof are written at the end of the answer)

---

Proof for $2^{y-2}\mid x\implies 3^x\equiv 1\pmod{2^y}$

If $2^{y-2}\mid x$, then, from $(1)$, $3^{x}-1$ is divisible at least by $2^y$. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

Proof for $3^x\equiv 1\pmod{2^y}\implies 2^{y-2}\mid x$

It is easy to see that $4\not\mid 3^{\text{odd}}-1$.

The claim follows from this and $(1)$. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

Finally, let us prove $(1)$ by induction on $a$.

For $a=1$, we have $3^{2s}-1\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\pmod{2^3}$. Also, writing $s=2u+1$, we have $$3^{2s}-1=9^{2u+1}-1=9\cdot 81^u-1\equiv 9-1\equiv 8\pmod{2^4}.$$

Suppose that $(1)$ holds for some $a$.

Then, we have
$$3^{2^{a+1}s}-1=(3^{2^as})^2-1=(2^{a+2}t+1)^2-1=2^{2a+4}t^2+2^{a+3}t=2^{a+3}t'$$
where $t'$ is odd. $\quad\blacksquare$